# NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on nul: "_set"

Tags: list, flutter, listview

I am new to flutter.
I am trying make Total of Listview textfield.
But when insert line below in ItemBuilder

**t1[index] = TextEditingController();**

it throows error
**NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on nul: "_set"**
but when.  I have declare variable of List T1
for this purpose .Please solution for
total of textfield in ListView.

Sample code is attached.
Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List data = ["apple kg", "banana kg", "mango kg"];
  List<TextEditingController> t1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                t1[index] = TextEditingController();
                return Container(
                  width: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 0.5),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(data[index]),
                      TextField(),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Text("TOTAL SALE"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In declare:

```
  List<TextEditingController> t1=[];
```

In `ListView.builder` change `t1[index] = TextEditingController();` to

```
  if(index<ti.length){
     t1[index] = TextEditingController();
  }else{
     t1.add(TextEditingController());
  }
```

The reason is that you declare an empty list, and there is no element in the list, you try to set the TextEditingController to null.

Comment: sorry, my bad .